# Firebase firestore.doc not returning data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to query a document that I've set up using the firebase console I don't get anything back that looks like the data I've entered.

I've tried console logging the collection as well but get nothing back from that either. I've checked that the firebase config is correct but it seems fine.

```
let doc = firebase.firestore().doc(`users/${this.userId}`)
    console.log('doc', doc)
```

In trying to console.log the document I get the following response

[image: console.log]

I was expecting the collection or just the document to appear in the console log with all the data from firestore.

Comment: That is only the reference to the location. You need to actually [get the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document) from that location.

Comment: Feel like writing an answer with the first relevant code snippet from that documentation page Andre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three concepts to know here:

1. [Documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#documents) a lightweight record that contains fields, which map to values
2. [References](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#references) Every document in Cloud Firestore is uniquely identified by its location within the database.
3. The data which is the content of a single document, retrieved using .data()

`let docRef = db.collection("objects").doc("singleObjectWithDataFields")` is the reference.

`docRef.get().then(function(doc){` returns the document

`doc.data()` returns the data fields, which map either to values, or to maps which are complex nested objects

Comment: Thank you ersin-ertan, that was a very helpful explanation.